# Saving extracted column to a txt file in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, text

I need some help writing the values from a column to a text file in ascending order.

The code I currently have creates a directory called `values` and saves the values extracted from the column to .txt file but it is not in ascending order as I would like.

```py
values_dir=os.path.join(cwd, 'values')

if not os.path.exists(values_dir):
    os.mkdir(values_dir)
    
with open(os.path.join(values_dir, 'values.txt'), "w") as txt_file:
    for name, group in split_location:
        txt_file.write(str(name) + '\n')
```

The code saves my values as

```
data23
data17
data88
```

I would like it to save as

```
data17
data23
data88
```

If someone could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated, thank you.

## Edit

I split 2 large dataframes by unique values in fields `Data` and `Data_Unit`

```py
datafile = pd.read_csv('location.csv')

datafile_large = pd.read_csv('large.csv')

split_location = datafile.groupby('Data')
split_large = datafile_large.groupby('Data_Unit')
```

I then loop through the groups and save the split dataframes to sub-directories based on their unique values, whilst  maintaining the parent file name.

```py
for name, group in split_location:
    sub_dir = os.path.join(cwd, name)
    if not os.path.exists(sub_dir):
        os.mkdir(sub_dir)
    group = group.drop(['Data'], axis=1)
    group.to_csv(sub_dir + "/location.csv", index=0)

for name, group in split_large:
    sub_dir = os.path.join(cwd, name)
    if not os.path.exists(sub_dir):
        os.mkdir(sub_dir)
    group = group.drop(['Data_Unit'], axis=1)
    group.to_csv(sub_dir + "/large.csv", index=0)
```

Lastly I create the `values.txt` file as mentioned in the beginning. But would like the values saved in the .txt file in ascending order.

```py
values_dir=os.path.join(cwd, 'values')

if not os.path.exists(values_dir):
    os.mkdir(values_dir)
    
with open(os.path.join(values_dir, 'values.txt'), "w") as txt_file:
    for name, group in split_location:
        txt_file.write(str(name) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
    names, groups = map(list, zip(*split_location))
    names.sort()
    
    for name in names:
        txt_file.write(str(name) + '\n')
```

Instead of:

```py
    for name, group in split_location:
        txt_file.write(str(name) + '\n')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your Answer :) Unfortunately the values still aren't saving in ascending order and I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: What does `split_location` look like?

Comment: I've added some edits to give a broader explanation on what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks again @Mady Daby

Comment: @Kam-ALIEN Does changing your original for loop to `for name, group in split_location.sort_values('Data'):` work?

Comment: I did attempt this method previously but  was presented AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'...Thanks for your reply

Comment: What about `for name, group in datafile.sort_values('Data').groupby('Data'):`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's built-in `sorted` function or the `sort` method of a list. Another answer shows the sort method so I'm using sorted here.

Also use `pathlib` for python 3.

```
from pathlib import Path

values_dir = Path.home() / 'values'
values_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# step one: get a list of names
# from your example, split_location looks like
# an iterable of two-item tuple or list
names = sorted([str(item[0]) for item in split_location])

# step two: write the list of sorted names
# you can write just one string by joining your
# list of names with newline characters
newf = values_dir / 'values.txt'
newf.write_text('\n'.join(names))
```